# Suitable hadoop framework for ubuntu

Tags: hadoop, bigdata, nosql

I want to start working with Hadoop and BigData. I need an easy graphical interface to start. I try Hue but I couldn't get it configured.

Please help me to choose my suitable Hadoop.
I use Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some distributions like Cloudera or Hortonworks but their package needs high machine configuration. For example RAM + 16GB and sometimes it's not possible for the user. In addition, they include some Hadoop related project that user doesn't need at all. If you want to enter this field seriously I strongly recommend installing Hadoop on your own. Doing that you do some configuration and will get familiar with many Hadoop concepts.

You can start using [this](http://www.bogotobogo.com/Hadoop/BigData_hadoop_Install_on_ubuntu_single_node_cluster.php) install tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 major Hadoop distributions that you can start with.

- Cloudera
- Hortonworks
- MapR

Each one of them has a UI installer and manager. I think the best for you would be though, to use the virtual environment that these vendors provide.

The  [Hortonworks Developer Sandbox](http://hortonworks.com/products/hortonworks-sandbox/) is an image including Hue as UI to get started. However, the downloadable sandbox image is based on CentOS.

If you want to install a Hortonworks Distribution on Ubuntu, you need to run an Ambari installation ([Downloads - Hortonworks Hadoop](http://hortonworks.com/hdp/downloads/)). Be aware that Hue is not included into the default Ambari installation, but Hue can be installed easily separately. To run properly, Hue on Hortonworks still needs Python 2.6.x.

Answer (score 1):

I think Cloudera,sandbox(by hortonworks) is a easy way.Hard way is installation to Ubuntu.Also i have ubuntu 14.04 and Hadoop(hive,pig),Apache spark exist and i dont need open virtual machine.